# WGS84 buildings to Collada tile

Tags: kml, google-earth, collada

I've got building "footprints" in WGS84. Based on a regular grid I've 
got to produce Collada "tiles" containing 3D buildings (extruded 
footprints). These collada files are finally referenced by KML files 
to produce a kmz dataset.

Everything is working quite fine. However my first tests have shown 
gaps in GE between the aerial photography layer and my Collada 
buildings. What should be the best strategy to convert WGS84 polygon 
coordinates to local Collada coordinates ? What is best way to take 
into account the ellipsoidic shape of the earth for GE ?

Thanx in advance

Franck

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to import them into [Google SketchUp](http://sketchup.google.com/) and use SketchUp to do final placement.